# Clean way to check an empty inside a map in Java

Tags: java, sql, dictionary, jdbc, is-empty

I have a map with data I got from my database and I am having trouble to find an optimal way to check if the value of one of my fields is empty.

The thing is like this. I got 4 values inside a map: A1, A2, A3, and A4.   If A4 has data, I just need to return A4, else I return a concatenation of A1, A2, A3.

The thing is that I am trying to check if A4 is empty without transforming it to string (I can always do it, but I have the feeling that there should be a better way to check this).

The query that returns the data is something like this:

```
String query = "select gactb021.des021, "
                + " gactb032.nif032, gactb032.noc032, gactb032.no032,gactb032.ap1032, gactb032.ap2032, "
                + " sdt031.facto, sdt031.cprof, sdt031.ipago from sdt031 "
                + " INNER JOIN GACTB021 ON sdt031.cacto = GACTB021.act021 "
                + " INNER JOIN GACTB032 ON sdt031.cprof = GACTB032.fact032 "
                + " where NASET = VARIABLE1"
                + " and FACTO <= VARIABLE2 AND FACTO >= VARIABLE3"
                + " AND (SPAGE = 'R'  OR SPAGE = 'M' OR SPAGE = 'F')";
```

This data is transformed to a `List<Map>` inside my Java code and in a for loop I retrieve all the info I want.

Here is an example of the function that I currently have:

```
private static String formatNomFact(Map elements) {
    String issueVar = Objects.toString(elements.get("noc032"), "");
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(issueVar)) { 
        //Do 1
    } else {
        //Do 2
    }
    return "";
}
```

I would like to know a way to improve my code instead of doing it this way.

Comment: What is the type of "A4"? As an aside, using a raw `Map` is a bad idea, you should parameterize it with the types of the key and value.

Comment: is an String, thats why i though of doing a To String, but the map is a <String, Object>

Comment: If `elements.get("noc032")` is a `String` already, you don't need to transform it.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, is an Object so the StringUtils doesn´t work yet, that´s why i was checking for a method to check if the object ios empty or null instead of transforming it to String and check then.  StringUtils.isBlank(elements.get("noc032") 
 doesn´t work

Comment: What does it mean for an `Object` to be "empty"?

Comment: noc032 can be: 1: an empty ""  2: null  3: have info. currently i am looking for a way to discard options 1 and 2. I don´t know if i can improve the query so that it doesn´t return "noc032" in case 1 and 2 (to use the Map.HAS("key") or instead if there is a way to check empty or null without having to transform my object to String

Comment: I think you may be confused between the type of the `Map` being `Map<String,Object>`, so that the compile time type of `elements.get("noc032")` is `Object`, and the fact that the value returned is, at runtime, a `String`? You don't need to convert it, just use `instanceof` to cast it to a `String`.

Comment: So, `A4` is a *value* associated with a *key* `"noc032"` can be either `null`, or an *empty string*, or a string holding the data you need? If so, `instanceof` check is redundant, because even placed into a `Map` of row-type it's still a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any conversion, because (as far as I can tell) at runtime your `Map` contains a `String` for that key:

```java
        Object issueVar = elements.get("noc032");
        if (issueVar instanceof String s) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(s)) { //isEmpty checks for null too
                ...
            } else {
                return s;
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected String for key noc032 but got '"
              + issueVar + "'");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I got `4` values inside a map: `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, and `A4`. If `A4` has data, I just need to return A4, else I return a concatenation of `A1`, `A2`, `A3`.
>
> I am trying to check if `A4` is empty without transforming it to string

Since you have a Map of row-type which is equivalent of `Map<Object,Object>` eventually you would need to coerce the value retried from the map to a string type `String`. But instead of casting string value, you can invoke method `toString()` on it, which returns the initial string when applied on a `String`.

And since the values can not be anything but `String`s `instanceof` check is **redundant**.

To tackle both of your concerns whether the value is *non-null* and *not empty* you can use [`Map.getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) and standard [`String.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) (*no need to employ* `StringUtils` *from Apache Commons for that*).

That's how it might look like:

```
private static String formatNomFact(Map elements) {
    String issueVar = elements.getOrDefault("noc032", "").toString();
    
    return !issueVar.isEmpty() ? issueVar : // alternative option ;
}
```